# Spring Security ignores Spring MessageSource bundles

Tags: spring, spring-security

I recently moved my message property files files to a directory that is not the class root.

Now, I'm finding that Spring Security ignores the message bundles and uses its defaults. How can I makes Spring Security use this messageSource?

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/i8n/ui</value>
            <value>/WEB-INF/i8n/ValidationMessages</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="cacheSeconds" value="10000" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="useCodeAsDefaultMessage" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Looks like if I move the i8n directory to the classes directory, it works. Looks like a bug in Spring Security

Comment: Do you have this been configured in the same application context as Spring Security (i.e. `ContextLoaderListener`) if not Spring Security will not detect it.